# Is it correct to use "giving rating"?

Tags: idioms, grammaticality

For example, is "they gave the same rating to the movie" a proper usage?

Comment: According to me, yes it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say of two banks that

> They gave the same rates.

But you would be slightly more likely to say

> They offered the same rates.

As for "a giving rate" that is an exceedingly odd construction. You might refer to "a given rate" but that would be in a different context.

**Edit (after much colloquy in the comments):**

Now it's clear you're talking about *ratings* as in "movie ratings" I would say that the verb to use is *give*. So it is quite all right to say:

> They gave identical ratings to the movie.

Note that if you use the word *same* you might be forcing yourself to use the singular:

> They gave the same rating to the movie.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I didn't mean the rate which banks use, I edited question for clarification.

Comment: @metdos: Well, are you talking about *ratings* then, not *rates*?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated again.

Comment: @metdos: Edited to address the new information.